# How to replace infinite sleep in async code?

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-service-fabric

I have code in service fabric that init service and wait forever (it is from template generated from VS). I replaced this `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` with `async await`, but I don't know what to do with `Thread.Sleep` - `Task.Delay` with max of TimeSpan will end sometime I think.

```
ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("Stateless1Type",
                    context => new Stateless1(context)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

// Prevents this host process from terminating so services keep running.
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: is there any specific reason you have to change it? What the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It is not a big problem - I would like to change code to clean async/await without GetAwaiter(), but this Thread.Sleep prevents me from doing this - I could live with old code but I just wonder if it is doable to rewrite it to pure async

Comment: That is pretty unlikely to come to a good end.  Because as soon as you make it async, the host process will in fact terminate.  No continuations in a terminated process ;)

Comment: That depends on how the toplevel async is called - in for instance a `async Task Main() {}` an `await Task.Delay()` would work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
await Task.Delay(-1);
```

> The number of milliseconds to wait before completing the returned
>   task, or -1 to wait indefinitely.

Comment: Or `await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);`